# My functions in javascript are incorrectly overlapping incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, css, time

for some reason the two "parts" of my javascript are interfering with one another. I know this is the case because if you delete the color changing part, the clock suddenly shows up. The intended result is that the clock shows up in front of the colors. I can't determine why this is happening. Thanks!

```js
var div = document.getElementById("full");

function pad(n, width, z) {
  z = z || '0';
  n = n + '';
  return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
}

function getclockColor() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = String(today.getHours());
  var m = String(today.getMinutes());
  var s = String(today.getSeconds());
  var color = '#' + pad(h, 2) + pad(m, 2) + pad(s, 2);
  return color;
}

function changeColor() {
  div.style.backgroundColor = getclockColor();
}

setInterval(changeColor, 1000);

function clock() {
  var time = new Date(),

    hours = time.getHours(),

    minutes = time.getMinutes(),


    seconds = time.getSeconds();

  document.querySelectorAll('.clock')[0].innerHTML = harold(hours) + ":" + harold(minutes) + ":" + harold(seconds);

  function harold(standIn) {
    if (standIn < 10) {
      standIn = '0' + standIn
    }
    return standIn;
  }
}
setInterval(clock, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#full {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.clock {
  font-size: 4em;
  z-index: 1;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/zanolon/Desktop/Color Clock/Clock.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="full"></div>
  <div class="clock"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JS. Your clock is simply behind the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `#full` element's `z-index` to `-1` to push it behind the clock.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#full {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.clock {
  font-size: 4em;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/zanolon/Desktop/Color Clock/Clock.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="full"></div>
    <div class="clock"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var div = document.getElementById("full");

    function pad(n, width, z) {
        z = z || '0';
        n = n + '';
        return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
    }

    function getclockColor() {
        var today = new Date();
        var h = String(today.getHours());
        var m = String(today.getMinutes());
        var s = String(today.getSeconds());
        var color = '#' + pad(h, 2) + pad(m, 2) + pad(s, 2);
        return color;
    }

    function changeColor() {
        div.style.backgroundColor = getclockColor();
    }

    setInterval(changeColor, 1000);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function clock() {
        var time = new Date(),

            hours = time.getHours(),

            minutes = time.getMinutes(),


            seconds = time.getSeconds();

        document.querySelectorAll('.clock')[0].innerHTML = harold(hours) + ":" + harold(minutes) + ":" + harold(seconds);

        function harold(standIn) {
            if (standIn < 10) {
                standIn = '0' + standIn
            }
            return standIn;
        }
    }
    setInterval(clock, 1000);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow... I'm so stupid. Sorry for wasting your time :(

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to call in separate `setInterval`, just call one function containing the two calls.
- The position absolute is positioning the div on the clock div.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("full");

function pad(n, width, z) {
  z = z || '0';
  n = n + '';
  return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
}

function getclockColor() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = String(today.getHours());
  var m = String(today.getMinutes());
  var s = String(today.getSeconds());
  var color = '#' + pad(h, 2) + pad(m, 2) + pad(s, 2);
  return color;
}

function changeColor() {
  div.style.backgroundColor = getclockColor();
}

//setInterval(changeColor, 1000);

function clock() {
  var time = new Date(),

    hours = time.getHours(),

    minutes = time.getMinutes(),


    seconds = time.getSeconds();
  document.getElementsByClassName('clock')[0].innerHTML = harold(hours) + ":" + harold(minutes) + ":" + harold(seconds);

  function harold(standIn) {
    if (standIn < 10) {
      standIn = '0' + standIn
    }
    return standIn;
  }
}
setInterval(function() {
  clock();
  changeColor();
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#full {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.clock {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 4em;
  z-index: 999;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/zanolon/Desktop/Color Clock/Clock.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="full"></div>
  <div class="clock"></div>
</body>

</html>
```